# How do I route HTTPS encrypted packets without decrypting it?

Tags: nginx, proxy

We have a scenario where I have two applications that are running in virtual machines. They will both serve traffic on ports 80/443, but on different host names. One of the containers is vendor-provided, and they will decrypt HTTPS traffic within the container.

Can I configure NGINX (or another tool) to route traffic to a certain VM based on the targetted hostname (perhaps via SNI) *without* decrypting the packets in the proxy?

For example:

myapp1.example.com:443 -> NGINX -> 10.0.0.1:8443 (terminate HTTPS on VM)
vendor1.example.com:443 -> NGINX -> 10.0.0.1:9443 (terminate HTTPS on VM)

Answer (score 9):

This can be achieved by using the `nginx` [ngx_stream_ssl_preread_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_ssl_preread_module.html). Here's an example configuration:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

stream {
    upstream server1 {
        server 192.0.2.125:443;
    }

    upstream server2 {
        server 192.0.2.126:443;
    }

    map $ssl_preread_server_name $upstream {
        hostnames;
        .server1.example.com server1;
        .server2.example.com server2;
    }

    server {
        listen 443;
        listen [::]:443;

        ssl_preread on;
        proxy_pass $upstream;
    }
}
```

The `upstream` directive is used to define the server to send traffic to. Then the `map $ssl_preread_server_name` allows `nginx` to read the SNI value of the request from the client to properly direct traffic to the right `upstream` box.

This will **ONLY** work, if the client sends a valid SNI value. This also allows the use of client-certificates for authentication since the TLS connection isn't completed until AFTER `nginx` sends the traffic to the remote end-point.

Comment: This seems like it would work. I would either need to build nginx from source to enable that support, or run their docker image which seems like it has support already.

Comment: Depending on your server, I believe they have repos that maintain their stable version. This is how I deploy it on my Debian machines.